# Different templates for one AngularJS application

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I am trying to create in AngularJS "normal" WEB application, which will have different:

1. [template with login form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btNL0.png)
2. [template with content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HF1T2.jpg)

When open application - show login form, after submitting credentials to server and authorize, show contents template, when logout - show login form.

How this is possible to achieve with AngularJS? Thanks!

**Updated**

I am using Angular-UI router and there is no problem with routes to `/login` or `/content` :) I have HTML structure:

```
<html>
<body ng-app="MyApp">
    <header>...</header>
    <section>
        <nav>...</nav>
        <section ui-view> THERE ARE CONTENT </section>
    </section>
    <footer>...</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

In `ui-view` (Angular-UI `ng-view`) I include "modularized" templates with controllers and all works fine.

But how can I change main template for "/login" to something like:

```
<html>
<body ng-app="MyApp">
    <section ui-view> THERE SHOULD BE LOGIN FORM</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It might be best to follow a tutorial on AngularJS before asking a question about it here. For example: http://www.revillweb.com/tutorials/angularjs-in-30-minutes-angularjs-tutorial/

Comment: Yes, you are right - I need some tutorial about this, but your given, doesn't answer my question. I tried to specify in my update.

Comment: I've extended my answer accordingly to your extension ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a $route

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

you can then specific a route i.e. `/login` and after successfull login redirect user to `/content`

if you don't want to use route and views you can use ng-include and dynamicaly load partials but IMHO routes looks cleaner to user

--extended--
I think you are missing the basics here from ui-view setup

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router#get-started checkout step 5

index.html

```
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="navigationCtrl">
<section id="main" ng-include="currentPartial.partial+'.html'"></section>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('testApp', [])
  .controller('navigationCtrl', function navigationCtrl($scope){
      $scope.currentPartial = {partial:'login'}
  })
```

login.html

```
<div><button ng-click="currentPartial.partial = 'content'">switch to content</button>
```

content.html

```
<div><button ng-click="currentPartial.partial = 'login'">switch to login</button>
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, but it is only part of it. I tried to specify in my update.

Comment: Thank for answer, but you give me information to work with one layout, but many partials. I am interested how to change layout. Or you think that I need to define `ui-view` for the `body` and include all things there without changing layout?

Comment: Why does the login page need to have the ng-view tag? It is a seperate layout to the rest of the site so it doesn't need it.

Comment: Or you could show the headers and footers depending on whether or not the user is loggedin e.g. <header ng-show="user.isLoggedIn">..</header>

Comment: So, as I understand there are no possibility to change layout in one app. Then the best solution is to make one big container and show/hide  header/menu/content/footer or login form based on url/state?

Comment: I've added an example of how to use ng-include which might be what you need if you want to load completely different layout

Comment: You answered something different what I was needed, but you put me on the right way. I found my solution using `ui-router` nested states, using abstraction. I marked your answer as correct. Thank you anyway!